# Error de contraseñas usando bcryptjs

Tags: html5, nodejs, mysql-workbench, npm, bcryptjs

Hola a todos tengo un problema usando el modulo de encriptacion de contraseñas de bcryptjs.
Hago registro  de un nuevo usuario con su nombres completos, su nombre de usuario y su contraseña como esta en el formulario, sin embargo cuando uso los datos de ingreso me dice que la contraseña es incorrecta aun poniendo una contraseña de prueba facil como "123" pero me manda el mismo error, contraseña incorrecta, dejo los formularios y los demas modulos que estoy usando

muchas gracias por su colaboración

$ npm version
9.8.1

Formulario de Registro

```html
<div class="container p-4">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 mx-auto">
        <div class="card text-center">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h3>Registrarse</h3>
            </div>
            <img src="" alt="">
            <div class="card-body">
                <img src="/img/agregar-usuario.png" alt="signup" class="m-3" >
                <br>

                <form action="/signup" method="POST">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="nombresCompletos" class="form-label">Nombres Completos</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombresCompletos"
                            placeholder="Nombres y Apellidos" autofocus required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="nombreUsuario" class="form-label">Nombre de Usuario</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombreUsuario" placeholder="nombreusuario"
                            required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password" class="form-label">Contraseña</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="contraseña"
                            required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <br>
                        <div class="d-grid gap-2">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary">Registarse</button>
                            <a href="/vehicles/" class="btn btn-light" type="button">Cancelar</a>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Formulario de ingreso

```html
 <div class="container p-4">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 mx-auto">
            <div class="card text-center">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h3>Iniciar Sesión</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <img src="/img/acceso.png" alt="loginUserIcon" class="m-3">
                    <form action="/signin" method="POST">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="nombreUsuario" class="form-label">Nombre de Usuario</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombreUsuario" placeholder="nombreusuario"
                                required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="password" class="form-label">Contraseña</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Contraseña"
                                required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <br>
                            <div class="d-grid gap-2">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary">Iniciar Sesión</button>
                                <a href="/" class="btn btn-light" type="button">Cancelar</a>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Modulo de encriptación

```js
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
    const helpers = {};
    
    helpers.encryptPassword = async (password) => {
        try {
            const saltRounds = 10;
            const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(saltRounds);
            const hash = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);
            return hash;
        } catch (error) {
            throw error; 
        }
    };
    
    helpers.matchPassword = async (password, hashedPassword) => {
        try {
            const passwordMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, hashedPassword);
            return passwordMatch;
        } catch (error) {
            throw error; 
        }
    };
    
    module.exports = helpers;
```

Modulo de registro de usuarios y de ingreso

```js
const passport = require('passport');
    const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
    const pool = require('../database');
    const helpers = require('../lib/helpers');
    
    passport.use('local.signin', new LocalStrategy({
        usernameField: 'nombreUsuario',
        passwordField: 'password',
        passReqToCallback: true
    }, async (req, nombreUsuario, password, done) => {
        try {
            const rows = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM Usuario WHERE nombreUsuario = ?', [nombreUsuario]);
            if (rows.length > 0) {
                const usuarioEncontrado = rows[0];
                const validPassword = await helpers.matchPassword(password, usuarioEncontrado.password);
                if (validPassword) {
                    done(null, usuarioEncontrado, req.flash('success', 'Bienvenido ' + usuarioEncontrado.nombresCompletos));
                } else {
                    done(null, false, req.flash('error', 'Contraseña incorrecta para ' + usuarioEncontrado.nombreUsuario + '. Verifique e intente nuevamente'));
                }
            } else {
                done(null, false, req.flash('error', 'El usuario ' + nombreUsuario + ' no se encuentra registrado'));
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            done(error);
        }
    }));
    
    
    passport.use('local.signup', new LocalStrategy({
        usernameField: 'nombreUsuario',
        passwordField: 'password',
        passReqToCallback: true
    }, async (req, nombreUsuario, password, done) => {
        const { nombresCompletos } = req.body;
        const newUser = {
            nombreUsuario,
            password,
            nombresCompletos
        };
        newUser.password = await helpers.encryptPassword(password);
        const result = await pool.query('INSERT INTO Usuario (nombresCompletos, nombreUsuario, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', [newUser.nombresCompletos, newUser.nombreUsuario, newUser.password]);
        newUser.idUsuario = result.insertId;
        req.flash('success','Usuario '+nombresCompletos+' registrado Correctamente');
        return done(null, newUser);
    }));
    
    passport.serializeUser((nombreUsuario, done) => {
        done(null, nombreUsuario.idUsuario);
    });
    
    passport.deserializeUser(async (idUsuario, done) => {
        const rows = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM Usuario WHERE idUsuario = ? ', [idUsuario]);
        done(null, true);
    });
```

Modulo de autenticación

```js
const express = require('express');
    const router = express.Router();
    
    const passport = require('passport')
    
    router.get('/signup', (req, res) => {
        res.render('auth/signup');
    });
    
    router.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local.signup', {
        successRedirect: '/signin',
        failureRedirect: '/signup',
        failureFlash: true,
    }));
    
    router.get('/signin', (req, res) => {
        res.render('auth/signin');
    });
    
    router.post('/signin',(req,res,next) => {
        passport.authenticate('local.signin',{
            successRedirect: '/profile',
            failureRedirect: '/signin',
            failureFlash: true
        })(req,res,next);
        
    });
    
    router.get('/profile', (req, res) => {
        res.send('Perfil de usuario')
    });
    
    module.exports = router;
```

La consola no muestra ningun error